# Domain Driven Design related aggregate roots and UI retrieval

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to grasp more and more of Domain Driven Design and follow best practices. So far this is my understanding:

- An aggregate is a collection of entities related to each other.
- The root of the aggregate is the entity the binds the relationship of the aggregate together.
- If the root is deleted everything within the confines of the aggregate must be deleted as well
- Aggregate roots can only reference each other via identities

My questions are:

If I have more than one aggregate related to each other, say Orders And Product Categories.

How should the application service handle the retrieval of an order and related product category?

Should the service have a reference to each repository of an order and product category, retrieve the order first, then retrieve the product category, and finally fill out a data transfer object referencing the information from both?

Something like this:

```
public OrderDto GetOrder(int id)
{
    var order = _orderRepo.GetById(id);

    var productCategory = _categoryRepo.GetById(order.ProductCategoryId);

    return new OrderDto 
                  { 
                     CustomerName = order.CustomerName, 
                     ProductCategoryName = productCategory.Name,
                     *..etc..*
                  };
}
```

Or is it over kill to keep the roots that decoupled if they are tightly related?

Or should the UI be making the calls to independent services for the complete picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some situations you may have to break the rules according to [Reasons to break the rules section](http://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_2.pdf)

The first one of them is presetation convenience, it's not a big deal when you just neeed to display one Order at a time, but the solution you mentioned causes N + 1 query problem if you need to list Order s.

Alternative solution is stick to the rule and use your persistence object for rendering ui(in list Order case) if you want to seperate(or have already seperated) your domain models from persistence infrastructure, some discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350605/persistence-ignorance-and-ddd-reality/18351640#18351640).

Comment: Thanks for that... I think he makes really good points in the "Reasons to break rules section". I personally think that rules are meant to be broken, only after you have a complete understanding of the rules. I'm still learning :)

Comment: I think this rule aims to prevent from modifying two Aggregate in one transaction naturally, actually it does not matter much if your team use Aggregate reference but follow the rule of not modifying multiple Aggregate in one transaction by team discipline.

Answer (score 0):

Using the CQRS pattern in your application seems an option. The pattern fits well with DDD because it helps us in this kind of situation where we need a different mechanism for writing and reading data, you can read more about CQRS in this article https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html, so if you want to retrieve data for the purpose of display you don't need to get all the aggregate roots because invariance of the entity can't be invalid when reading data i.e the entity state is not changing.